# Using @Subcomponent android dagger 2.x not working

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I'm facing an issue while trying to use Dagger's subcomponent. When I try to build this I get this error.

> @Subcomponent.Builder setter methods must return void, the builder, or a supertype of the builder. Inherited method: create(T).

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

```
@FragmentScope
@Subcomponent(modules = [OnBoardingWelcomeFragmentModule::class])
interface OnBoardingWelcomeFragmentComponent: AndroidInjector<OnBoardingWelcomeFragment> {

  @Subcomponent.Builder
  interface Builder: AndroidInjector.Factory<OnBoardingWelcomeFragment>


}

@Module
open class OnBoardingWelcomeFragmentModule {

  @Provides
  @FragmentScope
  fun provideUI() = OnBoardingWelcomeFragmentUi()

  @Provides
  @ViewModelForDagger
  fun providesViewModelForDagger(sharedPrefsStorage: SharedPrefsStorage): OnboardingViewModel =
    OnboardingViewModel(sharedPrefsStorage)

  @Provides
  fun providesViewModelFactory(@ViewModelForDagger
                               viewModel: Lazy<OnboardingViewModel>): ViewModelFactory<OnboardingViewModel> =
    ViewModelFactory(viewModel)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should switch `AndroidInjector.Factory` to `AndroidInjector.Builder` instead which implements `AndroidInjector.Factory`.

```
abstract class Builder: AndroidInjector.Builder<OnBoardingWelcomeFragment>
```

The `Factory` interface adds a method for `dagger.android` to use which you would have to implement yourself, since Dagger doesn't know how to—hence the error.